# OGR: How to save shapefile to HDD?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, python-2.7

I'm new to OGR module and I can't figure out how to save new layer to my HDD. I allready have shapefile with lines and buffer and I want to clip lines with buffer.

```
from osgeo import ogr
os.chdir(r"workspace")

# Load shp with lines
driver_lines = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
datasource_lines = driver_lines .Open("lines.shp", 1)
layer_lines = datasource_lines.GetLayer()

# Load shp with buffer
driver_buffer = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
datasource_buffer = driver_buffer .Open("buffer.shp", 1)
layer_buffer = datasource_buffer.GetLayer()

# Create output shapefile
driver_clip = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
datasource_clip = driver_clip.CreateDataSource("clip.shp")
layer_clip = datasource_clip.CreateLayer("clip", geom_type = ogr.wkbLineString)

# Clipping
layer_lines.Clip(layer_buffer, layer_clip)
```

So I have a layer with clipped lines, but I don't know how to physicaly save it to disc.

Comment: Do you know the code examples from the [OGR/GDAL cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#save-the-convex-hull-of-all-geometry-from-an-input-layer-to-an-output-layer)? Seems like your only missing two more lines.

Comment: Do you mean datasource_clip.Destroy() command? Seems doesn't working.